# Repairing a corrupt mp4 - I'm having issues getting untrunc installed

Tags: video, 19.04, mp4, data-corruption, libav

Basically, I get the error "moov atom not found" when attempting to play an mp4 video on vlc or any other players.

Following the advice given on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/538829/repairing-corrupt-mp4?fbclid=IwAR2zWK6ZiF4sO9L63hXB7ywyYtvr4r8AnU5QshiiLiOQCS1c46wzhj4nSJg), I'm attempting to use untrunc to generate a new moov atom that will render my file playable. (I get the exact same error messages that [this user talks about in another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158154/mp4-files-get-corrupted-when-transfering-them-to-ubuntu-18-04?fbclid=IwAR2RDT8ocmGC9Jw_4XTqq1XfDraEOUbbLfNcQftKfMNWmxoJHPohvTm3r-Q)).

So, I've taken their advice and I tried [installing on Ubuntu using these instructions](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc). However, I ran into some issues on the terminal during the last step `g++ -o untrunc file.cpp main.cpp track.cpp atom.cpp mp4.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil`

[error while compiling source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT9MF.jpg)

So, I tried it again from the first step and got this error:

[installing prerequisite libraries (2nd time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEZe4.png)

So, making sure I'm in the right directory (untrunc is located in home), I try compiling the source code again, but get the same error:

[checking file location of untrunc-master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjcQE.png)

[same error_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i5me.png)

[same error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hc7j.png)

I'm by no means a power user, just a novice Ubuntu/Linux enthusiast. I figure you guys might know what's going on and how to solve this! I'd love to begin using untrunc so I can render my file playable.

Thank you for your insight and assistance

P.S. What is this? I can't create the tags "moov" or "untrunc" without having 300 reputation points?? :o

Comment: Regarding your P.S.: You cannot create tags unless you have created a certain amount of "trustworthiness" aka reputation.

Answer (score 4):

I created a snap version of untrunc : https://snapcraft.io/michaelp-anthwlock-untrunc

**install**:

```
sudo snap install michaelp-anthwlock-untrunc
```

**usage**:

```
michaelp-anthwlock-untrunc.untrunc -s ok.mp4 nok.mp4
```

The snap is based on https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc which is more uptodate than the original version of ponchio.

Comment: I am getting `Info: version '77b30ac' using ffmpeg '3.3.9' Info: reading ok.mp4 Could not open file: ok.mp4` - any idea? It is not much to go on.

Comment: Can you try the snap that the upstream author took over and maintains? https://snapcraft.io/untrunc-anthwlock (edge channel)

Comment: @make42 The ok.mp4 is the video similar to the broken file. It is used as copy source.

Comment: @AnttiRytsölä:  The issue was that the file ok.mp4 was on a different partition. Moving it to the same partition solved the problem.